# JSON to string variable dump

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

Is there a quick function to convert JSON objects received via `jQuery getJSON` to a string variable dump (for tracing/debugging purposes)?

Comment: Silly question - why was this flagged as spam?

Comment: for the same reason my questions get down-votes, sometimes users are inaccurate with their clicks!

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Yes, `JSON.stringify`, can be found [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), it's [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) in Firefox 3.5.4 and above.

*A JSON stringifier goes in the opposite direction, converting JavaScript data structures into JSON text. JSON does not support cyclic data structures, so be careful to not give cyclical structures to the JSON stringifier.* https://web.archive.org/web/20100611210643/http://www.json.org/js.html

```
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);
```

Comment: It's included in chrome also, but you've got a (huge) 404 on that json.org link

Comment: If you just want to log data with this just:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null));   pass null if you don't need a replacement function!

Answer (score 30):

You can use `console.log()` in Firebug or Chrome to get a good object view here, like this:

```
$.getJSON('my.json', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

If you just want to *view* the string, look at the [Resource view in Chrome](http://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial#resources) or the [Net view in Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network) to see the actual string response from the server (no need to convert it...you received it this way).

If you want to take that string and break it down for easy viewing, there's an excellent tool here: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: It's useful to add an error handler otherwise `getJSON` will fail silently and you'll struggle to understand why it doesn't work : add `.fail(function(jqxhr, status, error) { alert(status + ", " + error);})`.

Answer (score 13):

i personally use the [jquery dump plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Dump) alot to dump objects, its a bit similar to php's print_r() function
Basic usage:

```
var obj = {
            hubba: "Some string...",
            bubba: 12.5,
            dubba: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
        }
$("#dump").append($.dump(obj));
/* will return:
Object { 
     hubba: "Some string..."
     bubba: 12.5
     dubba: Array ( 
          0 => "One"
          1 => "Two"
          2 => "Three"
     )
}
*/
```

Its very human readable, i also recommend this site http://json.parser.online.fr/ for creating/parsing/reading json, because it has nice colors

Comment: this is really great, but it requires installing yet another plugin (and just for debug)

Comment: yeah, i know... but when im looking for answers i often find something usefull in the answers because my problem relates to the problem. this plugin might indeed be a bit overkill when you just have a simple problem :P

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code I use.  You should be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
function process_test_json() {
  var jsonDataArr = { "Errors":[],"Success":true,"Data":{"step0":{"collectionNameStr":"dei_ideas_org_Private","url_root":"http:\/\/192.168.1.128:8500\/dei-ideas_org\/","collectionPathStr":"C:\\ColdFusion8\\wwwroot\\dei-ideas_org\\wwwrootchapter0-2\\verity_collections\\","writeVerityLastFileNameStr":"C:\\ColdFusion8\\wwwroot\\dei-ideas_org\\wwwroot\\chapter0-2\\VerityLastFileName.txt","doneFlag":false,"state_dbrec":{},"errorMsgStr":"","fileroot":"C:\\ColdFusion8\\wwwroot\\dei-ideas_org\\wwwroot"}}};

  var htmlStr= "<h3 class='recurse_title'>[jsonDataArr] struct is</h3> " + recurse( jsonDataArr );
  alert( htmlStr );
  $( document.createElement('div') ).attr( "class", "main_div").html( htmlStr ).appendTo('div#out');
  $("div#outAsHtml").text( $("div#out").html() ); 
}
function recurse( data ) {
  var htmlRetStr = "<ul class='recurseObj' >"; 
  for (var key in data) {
        if (typeof(data[key])== 'object' && data[key] != null) {
            htmlRetStr += "<li class='keyObj' ><strong>" + key + ":</strong><ul class='recurseSubObj' >";
            htmlRetStr += recurse( data[key] );
            htmlRetStr += '</ul  ></li   >';
        } else {
            htmlRetStr += ("<li class='keyStr' ><strong>" + key + ': </strong>&quot;' + data[key] + '&quot;</li  >' );
        }
  };
  htmlRetStr += '</ul >';    
  return( htmlRetStr );
}

</script>
</head><body>
<button onclick="process_test_json()" >Run process_test_json()</button>
<div id="out"></div>
<div id="outAsHtml"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

something along this?

```
function dump(x, indent) {
    var indent = indent || '';
    var s = '';
    if (Array.isArray(x)) {
        s += '[';
        for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            s += dump(x[i], indent)
            if (i < x.length-1) s += ', ';
        }
        s +=']';
    } else if (x === null) {
      s = 'NULL';
    } else switch(typeof x) {
        case 'undefined':
            s += 'UNDEFINED';
            break;
        case 'object':
            s += "{ ";
            var first = true;
            for (var p in x) {
                if (!first) s += indent + '  ';
                s += p + ': ';
                s += dump(x[p], indent + '  ');
                s += "\n"
                first = false;
            }
            s += '}';
            break;
        case 'boolean':
            s += (x) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
            break;
        case 'number':
            s += x;
            break;
        case 'string':
            s += '"' + x + '"';
            break;
        case 'function':
            s += '<FUNCTION>';
            break;
        default:
            s += x;
            break;
    }
    return s;
}
```