# reading server response on JQuery/jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying out JQuery and jqGrid for the first time to do a standard CRUD frontend to a database. Following documentation, I managed to get the adding rows to work but I would like to issue a success message. I tried this:

```
$("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', {add:true, view:false, edit:false, del:false},
                   {},
                   {closeAfterAdd:true,
                    afterComplete: function(response, postdata, formid){
                            alert(response);
                    }
                   },
                   {},
                   {},
                   {});
```

The server side does the insert and echoes the success message that I'd like in the alert, but the alert dialog only says `[Object object]`. I would appreciate some help on how to handle the server response.

Comment: Depends on the content. If server sends json, look for solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334341/jquery-javascript-json-to-string-variable-dump

Comment: found the error, it's `response.responseText` to get the server response.

Comment: @Alleo it is not a JSON response in this case, simply an echo of a string. But because the reading of the JSON response for the data in the table is done behind the scenes, I didn't know how to take the response text manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of the `afterComplete` callback function has the same format as the first parameter of `complete` callback function of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). So it's [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax#jqXHR) or [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) (in case of usage old jQuery 1.4.x) depend of the used jQuery version.

So you should use `alert(response.responseText)` instead of `alert(response)`.

Comment: Thank you. The type of the response object is exactly what I need to find to fiddle with it :)

Comment: @ravl1084: You are welcome! I read just now that you have found the solution yourself. It' always better, because you will keep the knowledge much better in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are alerting the `response` parameter itself, not any specific property on that object.  I haven't used this callback before, but based on the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing):

> *response* is the data returned from the server (if any)

if you're returning any data from the server, you would refer to it as `alert(response.<property>);` instead of just `alert(response)`.

Again, I haven't used this callback specifically, so I'm not sure if there's a wrapping property for the data you send back or not, but basically, you need to reference the specific property you want to display, and not the `response` object only.

**UPDATE**: I see from your comment that you found the answer.  `alert(response.responseText)`.

I hope this helps!