# From JavaScript to Java

Tags: java, javascript, object

I'm developing a project in which I have a client side created with jQuery and a REST web service on the server side.

On the server side I user Jackson to automatically parse JSON strings and produce Java Objects, my problem is on the client side where I need to have something that automatically creates for me JSON strings to send to the server side. Is there such a framework which makes this kind of work?

Comment: See this previously answered question: [jQuery /Javascript - json to string variable dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334341). It should do what you need.

Comment: No, it's not what I need to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON 2 is javascript for for purpose, It can stringify an object to json string https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js